# Hadoop 2.7.3 Exception from container-launch, failed due to AM Container Exit code:127

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have installed Hadoop 2.7.3 stable version. I set all environment variables like JAVA_HOME, HADOOP_HOME, PATH etc.. I configured yarn-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml.

I uploaded sample files in HDFS. When I am executing the wordcount program in hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar using below command

```
bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar grep input output 'as[a-z.]+'
```

it is throwing me following exception.

```
    17/01/28 00:59:33 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 36
    17/01/28 00:59:33 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:36
    17/01/28 00:59:33 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1485582326336_0001
    17/01/28 00:59:34 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1485582326336_0001
    17/01/28 00:59:34 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://XXXX.local:8088/proxy/application_1485582326336_0001/
    17/01/28 00:59:34 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1485582326336_0001
    17/01/28 00:59:38 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1485582326336_0001 running in uber mode : false
    17/01/28 00:59:38 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
    17/01/28 00:59:38 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1485582326336_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1485582326336_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1485582326336_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: 127
    For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://XXXXXX.local:8088/cluster/app/application_1485582326336_0001Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
    Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
    Container id: container_1485582326336_0001_02_000001
    Exit code: 127
    Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=127: 
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


    Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127
    Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
    17/01/28 00:59:38 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
    17/01/28 00:59:38 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
    17/01/28 00:59:38 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/sumitdeshmukh/.staging/job_1485582326336_0002
    org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/<username>/grep-temp-155204726
```

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Seems that you are running `grep` not `wordcount`. Also what are `input` and `output`. Paths? Try providing absolute paths there.

Comment: This was solved when I kept hard coded paths in hadoop-env.sh for JAVA_HOME and JAVA. Though these environment variables are set, somehow Hadoop fails to recognize them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the java home.
In the hadoop-env.sh, make the following changes:

```
#export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home
```